# What does it mean for a function to be differentiable/continuous when the input is a function?

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, machine-learning

I have the loss function
$$L(h) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(h(x_i) - y_i)^2$$

$h$ is a function that spits out the predicted value when fed in a vector $x_i$. The domain then for $h$ is $\mathbb R^d$ and the codomain is $\mathbb R$. My homework is asking if $L$ is continuous or differentiable. The problem is I don't even know what this means because the input is a function from $\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ and not a single real-valued input. How are we defining continuity/differentiability for functions from $\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$? I am only familiar with the $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ epsilon-delta definition of continuity. This class is for my intro ML course, so nothing too rigorous is necessary.

Comment: If it's not too rigorous they likely just mean continuity/differetiability w.r.t the $h(x_i)$

Comment: @StiftungWarentest Can you elaborate?

Comment: You could use the definition of continuity of functions between metric spaces ($\forall \epsilon > 0\, \exists \delta > 0 \,:\, \lVert h-h'\rVert < \delta \implies \lvert L\left(h\right) - L\left(h'\right) \rvert < \epsilon$). Now you just need to decide on a meaningful distance between functions, e.g. the [L2-norm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/L2-Norm.html).

Comment: Judging by the machine learning context, I'd say that, given a certain function $h$, you have $L_h\colon \mathbb R^d\times \mathbb R^d \rightarrow \mathbb R$. Where did you get $L(h)$ from?

Comment: @GitGud I think $h$ goes from $\mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$. $L$ is the squared loss.

Comment: I would guess $h\colon \mathbb R ^d\rightarrow \mathbb R$, but where did you get the expression $L(h)$ from? Was it you? Did you get it from a textbook? Lecture notes?

Comment: @GitGud Homework. But it's just the squared loss. It's a very common loss function.

Comment: I'm talking about the expression $L(h)$, not the squared loss function. The squared loss function is as I described, in which case $L(h)$ makes no sense.

Comment: Non-mathematicians take too many liberties with writing mathematics. I think your confusion is a consequence of the confusion of the people giving you this material. One can only guess what they would mean if they knew how to write mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

As you are not in category theory or something weirder, what they mean in this context is if the composition is differentiable with respect to x_i. If h is differentiable, then the composition certainly is. You should differenciate L(h(x)) by x --> Two times the sum of the terms without the exponent and each of them multiplied by the derivative of h.