# Differentiating with respect to a function: is this the chain rule?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

If I have $f(g) = g^2 + 3g$, where $f$ and $g$ are just functions from the reals to the reals, is the derivative of $f$ with respect to $g$ AND NOT $x$: $2g + g$? If so, why? I learned the chain rule, but that's with respect to $x$, not a function. Why can we treat functions as if they're just ordinary numbers?

I'm asking because for my ML class, I have the loss function  $$L(h) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}(h(x_i) - y_i)^2$$
where $h$ is a function that spits out the predicted value when fed in a vector $x_i$. (Note: $h$ is a function that takes in a vector and spits out a real number, which is $h$'s prediction for the vector. This is in the context of ML.) The domain then for $h$ is $\mathbb R^d$ and the codomain is $\mathbb R$, and hence the domain for $L$ is $h : \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ and the codomain is $\mathbb R$. I want to know how to differentiate with respect to $h$, because I don't know how to differentiate with respect to a function.

Original post: [What does it mean for a function to be differentiable/continuous when the input is a function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4637998/what-does-it-mean-for-a-function-to-be-differentiable-continuous-when-the-input)

Comment: There is a concept of differentiating with respect to a function when you have a function that takes functions as input, but I suspect that's not what you're doing. Can you give some context?

Comment: @Ian That is what I'm doing. My original post is here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4637998/what-does-it-mean-for-a-function-to-be-differentiable-continuous-when-the-input

Comment: The $g$ is the input to function $f$, so is $g$ just a number here?

Comment: @peterwhy edited the post

Comment: The derivative is a mapping which depends on the point of evaluation and the direction of perturbation. Both of these in this context are functions, but this makes sense in a variety of other contexts (in general in any Banach space). If you call the derivative $L'(h,\delta h)$ then it is defined by the properties of being linear in $\delta h$ together with the equation $L(h+\delta h)-L(h)-L'(h,\delta h)=o(\delta h)$ as $\delta h \to 0$. (This is basically like the familiar limit definition except that it makes no sense to divide by a function.)

Comment: In nice cases you can use familiar calculus methods to evaluate the derivative even though it has this somewhat abstract definition. For example here you have $L(h+\delta h)=\sum_{i=1}^n (h(x_i)+\delta h(x_i)-y_i)^2=\sum_{i=1}^n (h(x_i)-y_i)^2 + 2(h(x_i)-y_i) \delta h(x_i)+\delta h(x_i)^2$ so the derivative is $L'(h,\delta h)=\sum_{i=1}^n 2(h(x_i)-y_i) \delta h(x_i)$, since that last term $\sum_{i=1}^n \delta h(x_i)^2$ behaves as $o(\delta h)$ as $\delta h \to 0$.

Comment: I assume what you wrote is just a typo rather than some misunderstanding, but $f'(g) = 2g + 3$, not $2g + g$.

Comment: Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative; But since your (non-linear functional  $L$) functional's domain is the space of functions (continuous? integrable? square-integrable? please explain), you need to define a norm on this space to be able to integrate. There are different usually non-equivalent norms.